# Why do valid questions get closed without providing any help?

Tags: discussion

I run into this problem often. Case in point:

[19.10 seems to have broken suspend on my MB Pro](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1184283/19-10-seems-to-have-broken-suspend-on-my-mb-pro?newreg=1e69fcb57d804b8c95e2144074697364)

This user has a reputation of 111, appears to be an active contributor, and actually has the same problem I came here looking for answer to, along with possibly 84 other people, who have viewed his question. It's incredibly unhelpful.

Comment: Related: [Are bugs necessarily off-topic?](https://meta.askubuntu.com/q/2448/816190), [What to do with questions that describe bugs?](https://meta.askubuntu.com/q/1317/816190) and [How do you tell when a question is a bug?](https://meta.askubuntu.com/q/5906/816190)

Comment: If you only knew how much I love that this was voted down. The entire incentive system for "helping" people on here is broken and perverse. People who do not buy into your incentive system fully are discouraged from helping at all. I've been helping people for years and have never needed someone to offer me "reputation points". Just weird.

Answer (score 15):

The reason for the close is given in the blue box above the question body

> "**Bug reports and problems specific to development version of Ubuntu**
>   should be [reported on Launchpad](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug) so that developers can see, track and
>   fix these issues."

<sup>***Note:*** This banner is visible only to the questioner and users with 3000+ reputation points</sup>

Bugs are explicitly off topic here, as per [the help](https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic), meaning this is not a "valid" question.

You state "It's incredibly unhelpful" but it is quite the opposite. Firstly the question had no answer, so won't be helping you or anyone else find a solution but the reason for closing gives the link to the correct place to report the bug and that is very helpful, seriously, go and report it on Launchpad, the developers will see it and they are the ones who can fix the issue, the more of you that go and report a bug, the more priority the devs will give to it and the quicker it will be fixed.

Comment: So, here's the thing... It wasn't a bug, it was a mis-configuration. How do I know? Because I had the same problem and I fixed it myself. The solution: edit /etc/gdm3/custom.conf to include the line:
`WaylandEnable=false` This detail matters because the author of the original question states he has an Nvidia GPU, which is broken with Wayland and is what is causing the sleep issue. Too bad nobody will see this because it was down-voted and a comment that is wrong was up-voted. I guess "it's a bug" has been decided...

Comment: @DavidShepard I've commented on the question with a link to your comment here. That should help keep your solution from falling into obscurity before a longer-term way to provide the information is found. That could be by reopening the question if people think it's not a bug, or by linking to a bug report where your solution is mentioned as a workaround. I recommend you edit your meta question to add what you said in your comment--if possible, in somewhat more detail, as the OP *didn't* say he had an Nvidia GPU, and I don't think every MacBook Pro has one. (Perhaps all of them from 2010 did?)

Comment: thank you both @DavidShepard and @EliahKagan. I think my issue is that I had no way of knowing that it's a bug before I posted the question. I have managed to work around it by using the proprietary Nvidia drivers, but they come with a bunch of different issues (glitchy weirdness at the bottom of the screen). Unfortunately, your `WaylandEnabled=false` fix doesn't appear to have worked for me.

Comment: Hey Mark, I have edited your post to make it up to date and relevant. But if you think my edits aren't justified, feel free to roll back the edit. Thanks :)

Comment: @Kulfy If the note you added to the post is valid, what do other users see? Is there any [meta.se] post about it, for example?

Comment: @Melebius According to [the blog post](https://stackoverflow.blog/2019/12/05/new-post-notices-improving-feedback-on-stack-overflow-questions/): *Post authors, privileged users and moderators are shown an expanded notice, which can show additional information that they need to know (e.g., why the question was closed) along with suggested actions that they may want to take (e.g., edit the question).* As of now I'm not aware of any meta post specific to off-topic situations but the notice looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ljkZh.jpg) to other users.

Answer (score -2):

I agree that others should have asked to see content of `journalctl -b-1` in comments. Then after reason for broken suspend was ascertained posted an answer if possible or advised to file a bug report if not possible to fix.

You have to appreciate these days there are many many questions being asked without enough volunteers to carefully and thoroughly address them. Subjectively I think things have gotten worse since mods went on strike over that legal thing.

The OP could have gamed the system by simply saying "suspend is not working" instead of saying "suspend broken after 19.04 to 19.10 upgrade". It seems silly but many a question will be answered when saying "X is broken". However if you say "X is broken because of Y" then they will say file a bug report against "Y". In reality when looking at `journalctl -b-1` it may say the problem is caused by "Z" and totally unrelated to "Y".

I guess we can call this the X-Y-Z problem of prematurely closing questions.